# Ansible playbook with variable

Tags: variables, ansible

Trying to run script with different arguments on different servers using ansible, example:

```
server 192.168.0.1 -> fabric.sh generic1 status
server 192.168.0.2 -> fabric.sh generic2dr status
server 192.168.0.3 -> fabric.sh generic3 status
```

How to use variables in playbook below?

It works when I create group for each server, but it's not efficient

```
---
- hosts: esb
  remote_user: root
  tasks:
  - name: Generic_1
    become_user: esb
    shell: "/home/fabric.sh generic1 status"
```

Host file:

```
[esb]
192.168.0.1
192.168.0.2
192.168.0.3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set per-host variables in your inventory.  For example, modify your inventory so it looks like this:

```
[esb]
192.168.0.1 fabric_args="generic1 status"
192.168.0.2 fabric_args="generic2dr status"
192.168.0.3 fabric_args="generic3 status"
```

And then use the `fabric_args` variable in your playbook:

```
---
- hosts: esb
  remote_user: root
  tasks:
  - name: Generic_1
    become_user: esb
    shell: "/home/fabric.sh {{ fabric_args }}"
```

For more information, read the [Using Variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html) and [Working with Inventory](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html) sections of the Ansible documentation.

Comment: Thank you for help, that's what I needed

Answer (score 0):

Next to [Basic inventory](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/network/getting_started/first_inventory.html#basic-inventory) there is [yaml – Uses a specific YAML file as an inventory source](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/inventory/yaml.html#yaml-uses-a-specific-yaml-file-as-an-inventory-source).

For example (fit the variables to your needs):

```
$ cat hosts
all:                                                                         
  hosts:                                                                     
    10.1.0.51:                                                               
    10.1.0.52:                                                               
    10.1.0.53:                                                               
  vars:                                                                      
    ansible_connection: ssh                                                  
    ansible_user: admin                                                      
    ansible_become: yes                                                      
    ansible_become_user: root                                                
    ansible_become_method: sudo                                              
    ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/local/bin/python3.6                     
    ansible_perl_interpreter: /usr/local/bin/perl                            
  children:                                                                  
    esb:                                                                     
      hosts:                                                                 
        10.1.0.51:                                                           
          run_string: "fabric.sh generic1 status"                            
        10.1.0.52:                                                           
          run_string: "fabric.sh generic2dr status"                          
        10.1.0.53:                                                           
          run_string: "fabric.sh generic3 status"
```

The play below

```
- hosts: esb
  tasks:
  - debug:
      var: run_string
```

gives (abridged):

```
ok: [10.1.0.51] => {
    "run_string": "generic1 status"
}
ok: [10.1.0.52] => {
    "run_string": "generic2dr status"
}
ok: [10.1.0.53] => {
    "run_string": "generic3 status"
}
```